# How to remove Group in Gerrit Code Review?

Tags: gerrit

Is it possible to delete group in Gerrit Code Review? May be some plugins or this action should be performed 'manually' in SQL-like manner (e.g. gerrit gsql)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to remove Gerrit groups using the [command line tools](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-index.html) or the [REST API](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-groups.html).

I have a script that removes a Gerrit group from the Gerrit database.

It basically does the following:

1) Check if the group exists in Gerrit:

```
if ssh -p 29418 USER@GERRIT-SERVER gerrit ls-groups -q GROUP > /dev/null
then
    # GROUP EXIST
else
    # GROUP DOESN'T EXIST
fi
```

2) Check if the group has access rights assigned in any project:

```
ssh -p 29418 USER@GERRIT-SERVER gerrit ls-projects --type ALL --has-acl-for GROUP > /tmp/ls-projects

if [[ -s /tmp/ls-projects ]]
then
    # GROUP HAS ACCESS RIGHTS ASSIGNED
else
    # GROUP DOESN'T HAVE ACCESS RIGHTS ASSIGNED
fi
```

Note: you need first to remove the group from any project access rights.

3) Search for the group id in the Gerrit database

```
SELECT group_id FROM account_group_names WHERE name = 'GROUP';
```

4) Remove the group from the Gerrit database

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM account_group_id            WHERE s        = 'GROUP-ID';
DELETE FROM account_group_by_id         WHERE group_id = 'GROUP-ID';
DELETE FROM account_group_by_id_aud     WHERE group_id = 'GROUP-ID';
DELETE FROM account_group_members       WHERE group_id = 'GROUP-ID';
DELETE FROM account_group_names         WHERE group_id = 'GROUP-ID';
DELETE FROM account_groups              WHERE group_id = 'GROUP-ID';
DELETE FROM account_group_members_audit WHERE group_id = 'GROUP-ID';
COMMIT;
```

**UPDATE**

This procedure does NOT work anymore for Gerrit v3.0.x and forward.